# Multiple document reads in node js Firestore transaction

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I want to perform a transaction that requires updating two documents using the previous values of those documents.

For the sake of the question, I'm trying to transfer 100 tokens from one app user to another. This operation must be atomic to keep the data integrity of my DB, so on the server side I though to use `admin.firestore().runTransaction`.

As I understand `runTransaction` needs to perform all reads before performing writes, so how do I read *both* user's balance before updating the data?

This is what I have so far:

```
db = admin.firestore();
const user1Ref = db.collection('users').doc(user1Id);
const user2Ref = db.collection('users').doc(user2Id);
transaction = db.runTransaction(t => {
    return t.get(user1Ref).then(user1Snap => {
        const user1Balance = user1Snap.data().balance;
        // Somehow get the second user's balance (user2Balance)
        t.update(user1Ref , {balance: user1Balance - 100});
        t.update(user2Ref , {balance: user2Balance + 100});
        return Promise.resolve('Transferred 100 tokens from ' + user1Id + ' to ' + user2Id);
    });
}).then(result => {
    console.log('Transaction success', result);
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Promise.all()` to generate a single promise that resolves when all promises in the array passed to it have resolved.  Use that promise to continue work after all your document reads are complete - it will contain all the results.  The general form of your code should be like this:

```
const p1 = t.get(user1Ref)
const p2 = t.get(user2Ref)
const pAll = Promise.all([p1, p2])
pAll.then(results => {
    snap1 = results[0]
    snap2 = results[1]
    // work with snap1 and snap2 here, make updates to refs...
})
```

Comment: Thanks! Does this enforce the transaction behavior? Looking for protection against the case `user1Ref` or `user2Ref` are written to before the `then()`..

Comment: The server enforces the transaction behavior, not the client.  The client has to observe the rules stated in the documentation.  Using the form I showed, all document reads will happen before documents writes, which is the important requirement here.

Comment: No, @DougStevenson, what Dori means is that what happens when a  ref is written outside the transaction.

Comment: This doesn't implement transaction behaviour.

Comment: @hkchakladar You still work with promises like this *inside* the transaction to make sure all the async work is observed.

Comment: @DougStevenson, yeah that make sense, it should be inside the transaction. I think it's same as using `getAll`, as answered by @Derrick below

Answer (score 6):

You can use `getAll`.  See documentation at https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.15.x/Transaction?authuser=0#getAll

Comment: This should be the selected answer