# Enforce firestore transactions from the server-side (When it involves multiple documents)

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

When we have multiple collections where both collections MUST always be updated together, we can use transactions to wrap multiple operations together, but a user can still modify the client-side code to stop complying with such an important rule.

Let's say we have a collection `/databases/accounts` which contains the field `balance` and another collection `/databases/transfers` where each document contains information about a money transfer operation ( I mean, of course, we would involve a cloud function for such sensitive kind of data but this is just a hypothetical example )

In other words, can we define a security rule that ensures that a user cannot add a document to the `transfers` collection unless they wrap it in a transaction that properly updates the affected accounts accordingly? (***And can not update an `account` document without adding transfer documents that justify the updates***)

***Note: I'm asking for a solution that does NOT involve cloud functions***

I read in the documentation that you can use `getAfter` to [validate atomic operations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#data_validation_for_atomic_operations) but it doesn't seem to be enough and there isn't enough examples. Here's my code so far

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /transfers/{transferId} {
      allow create: if request.auth != null &&
        getAfter(
          /databases/$(database)/documents/accounts/$(request.resource.data.fromAccountId)
        ).data.balance -
        get(
          /databases/$(database)/documents/$(request.resource.data.fromAccountId)
        ).data.balance === request.resource.data.amount &&
        getAfter(
          /databases/$(database)/documents/accounts/$(request.resource.data.toAccountId)
        ).data.balance ===
        get(
          /databases/$(database)/documents/$(request.resource.data.toAccountId)
        ).data.balance + request.resource.data.amount;
    }
    match /accounts/{accountId} {
      allow update: if request.auth != null &&
      (
        // What should I write here? How can I get a reference for the transfer being created along with this update?
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The only workaround I can think of is adding a reference to the ```last_transfer``` in the ```accounts``` collection, enforcing it and validating it, and then using it to validate that ```update``` on the account

Comment: Are these answers-[1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50350570/15774176) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56164532/15774176) helpful?